# Textarea on focus becomes a DIV, when that div is clicked it goes back to textarea? jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a node.js app to transfer code between two machines. The first step is to paste code into a text area, and press enter. Upon pressing enter, it turns into a div or a `<pre>` with code highlighting.

I have the communication set up already. The part that is leaving me stumped is how I can turn back the div into a textarea.

If I click outside of the textarea, it turns into a div, which is all well and good, but I can't get the second part working.

http://jsfiddle.net/GeJkU/1045/

HTML

```
<textarea id="chatText">123</textarea>
```

JS

```
$chatDiv = $('#chatDiv');
$chatText = $('#chatText');

$chatDivHtml = $chatDiv.val();
$chatTextHtml = $chatText.html();

function divClicked() {
    var divReplace = $("<div>").attr("id", "chatDiv").text($chatTextHtml);
    $chatText.replaceWith(divReplace);
    divReplace.click(editableTextBlurred);     
}

function editableTextBlurred() {
    console.log("clicked");
    var textReplace = $("<textarea />").attr("id", "chatText").val($chatDivHtml);
    $chatDiv.replaceWith(textReplace);
    $chatDiv.click(divClicked);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $chatText.click(divClicked);
});
```

Comment: You never update the variables with the new content... $chatDivHtml and $chatTextHtml always have the initial value when loaded.

Comment: Yeah true, I understand that, but it's not even replacing the element in the first place, nevermind the value.

Comment: And that is because you are not attaching the click to the right element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/GeJkU/1060/

Use `.live()` to attach events for dynamically generated elements, since you're using jquery 1.4 version. For higher versions, you need to use `.on()`

```
$('#chatText').click(divClicked);
$('#chatDiv').live('click', editableTextBlurred);

function divClicked() {
    var $chatText = $('#chatText'),
        $chatTextHtml = $chatText.val();
    var divReplace = $("<div>").attr("id", "chatDiv").text($chatTextHtml);
    $chatText.replaceWith(divReplace);
    $(divReplace).click(editableTextBlurred);
}

function editableTextBlurred() {
    var $chatDiv = $('#chatDiv'),
        $chatDivHtml = $chatDiv.text();
    console.log("clicked");
    var textReplace = $("<textarea />").attr("id", "chatText").val($chatDivHtml);
    $chatDiv.replaceWith(textReplace);
    $(textReplace).click(divClicked);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you call replaceWith the identified items are no longer in the DOM. If you want to attach your click event you need to use the other selector you set up.

```
function editableTextBlurred() {
    console.log("clicked");
    var textReplace = $("<textarea />").attr("id", "chatText").val($chatDivHtml);
    $chatDiv.replaceWith(textReplace);
    $chatText.click(divClicked);
}
```